# Using wxCode widgets (like wxScintilla, wxPlotCtrl) in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, wxglade

Good day all.

I am writing my open source application in python and chose wxPython for gui.
And I mentioned that wxWidgets has excellent set of custom controls called wxCode: (http://wxcode.sourceforge.net/), therefore I have a question:

Is there a way for using them with wxPython?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

**Scintilla**:

http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl-class.html

http://www.yellowbrain.com/stc/index.html

**wx.lib.plot**:

http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.plot-module.html